# How do I send data from raspberry pi to pc using push button

Tags: networking, python

I want to know how to send data from raspberry pi to pc using push button . For example, from a circuitry connected with the raspberry pi , i hit the push button then maybe it will sent to the pc/browser and show a message 1 for example and maybe click twice at one time then is displays a 0.

Comment: How is the pc connected to the raspberry pi? (Serial, Ethernet/WLAN, etc)

Answer (score 1):

To detect a button in GPIO, try the https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/the-gpio-utility/.

With a bash script you can use this tool to detect and send a signal to PC.

Now the second part, how the two will be connected? If LAN, you could use a simple webserver in your pi, with some push server or node js to run your script and show the result in the PC browser.